# Как сделать в скрипте привязку по факту к количеству окон на странице?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! В скрипте жестко указано количество окон на странице. А как сделать в скрипте привязку по факту к количеству окон на странице, чтобы он автоматически определял их количество? Благодарю!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var overlay = $('.overlay');
  var window = $('.window');
  var close = $('.close');
  $('.tab').bind('click', function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').show();
    $('.tab').removeClass('tab-selected');
    $('[id=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').addClass('tab-selected');
    overlay.show();
    window.show();
    window.css("top", $(this).offset().top + $(this).height());
  });
  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').hide();
    $('.tab').removeClass('tab-selected');
    overlay.hide();
    window.hide();
  });

  $('.next, .prev').on('click', function() {
    var obj = ($(this).hasClass("next")) ? window.find(".content:visible + .content") : window.find(".content:visible").prev(".content");
    var obj_id = (obj.length > 0) ? obj.attr("id") : (($(this).hasClass("next")) ? '1-content' : '4-content');
    var id = obj_id.split("-")[0];
    $(".content").hide();
    $("#" + obj_id).show();
    $(".tab").removeClass("tab-selected");
    $("#" + id).addClass("tab-selected");
    window.css("top", $("#" + id).offset().top + $("#" + id).height());
  });

});
```

```css
.tab {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-selected {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}

.window {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: gray;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="tab">1</div>
<div id="2" class="tab">2</div>
<div id="3" class="tab">3</div>
<div id="4" class="tab">4</div>
<div id="5" class="tab">5</div>
<div id="6" class="tab">6</div>

<div class="window">
  <div id="1-content" class="content">Текст 1</div>
  <div id="2-content" class="content">Текст 2</div>
  <div id="3-content" class="content">Текст 3</div>
  <div id="4-content" class="content">Текст 4</div>
  <div id="5-content" class="content">Текст 5</div>
  <div id="6-content" class="content">Текст 6</div>
  <div class="prev">&lt;</div>
  <div class="next">&gt;</div>
  <div class="close">X</div>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вам необходимо узнать количество окон с id *-content. В таком случае вам просто поможет свойство `$(selector).length` которое выводит количество блоков, удовлетворяющих selector, который в вашем случае должен быть `'[id*=-content]'`, т.е. получить количество таких блоков можно с помощью `$('[id*=-content]').length`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var overlay = $('.overlay');
  var window = $('.window');
  var close = $('.close');
  var blocks = $('[id*=-content]').length;
  
  // ================ Подсчитываем кол-во блоков
  $('.counter span').html($('[id*=-content]').length);
  // ===================================================
  
  $('.tab').bind('click', function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').show();
    $('.tab').removeClass('tab-selected');
    $('[id=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').addClass('tab-selected');
    overlay.show();
    window.show();
    window.css("top", $(this).offset().top + $(this).height());
  });
  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').hide();
    $('.tab').removeClass('tab-selected');
    overlay.hide();
    window.hide();
  });

  $('.next, .prev').on('click', function() {
    var obj = ($(this).hasClass("next")) ? window.find(".content:visible + .content") : window.find(".content:visible").prev(".content");
    var obj_id = (obj.length > 0) ? obj.attr("id") : (($(this).hasClass("next")) ? '1-content' : blocks+'-content');
    var id = obj_id.split("-")[0];
    $(".content").hide();
    $("#" + obj_id).show();
    $(".tab").removeClass("tab-selected");
    $("#" + id).addClass("tab-selected");
    window.css("top", $("#" + id).offset().top + $("#" + id).height());
  });

});
```

```css
.tab {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-selected {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}

.window {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: gray;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="tab">1</div>
<div id="2" class="tab">2</div>
<div id="3" class="tab">3</div>
<div id="4" class="tab">4</div>
<div id="5" class="tab">5</div>
<div id="6" class="tab">6</div>
<div id="7" class="tab">7</div>

<div class="window">
  <div id="1-content" class="content">Текст 1</div>
  <div id="2-content" class="content">Текст 2</div>
  <div id="3-content" class="content">Текст 3</div>
  <div id="4-content" class="content">Текст 4</div>
  <div id="5-content" class="content">Текст 5</div>
  <div id="6-content" class="content">Текст 6</div>
  <div id="7-content" class="content">Текст 7</div>
  <div class="prev">&lt;</div>
  <div class="next">&gt;</div>
  <div class="close">X</div>
</div>

<div class="counter">
  Количество блоков: <span></span>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: @LADYX дак вывод в строку - это просто пример того как вы можете получить кол-во этих блоков. Добавьте в моем коде эти же 2 блока - он будет выводить что блоков 6. Вот и смотрите как эту 6-ку я получаю и вот этим же способом подставляйте вместо 4 уже переменную

Comment: @LADYX изменил код - всё прекрасно работает. Не знаю в чем у вас сложности. Скорее всего в том что код не ваш и JS вы не знаете. Здесь не делают все за вас, а "наставляют на путь истинный". Что я собственно и сделал, объяснил как получить кол-во блоков. А уже как это использовать - вам нужно было собственноручно придумать, но....я уже это реализовал в измененном коде ответа